# How would you plug this old weeping drain hole, in a brick/concrete retaining wall

Tags: concrete, waterproofing, spray-foam

This little sunken porch area stays dry, mostly.  There's what looks like an old relief drain in the wall that lets water in.  Its kinda dirty in there, and very uneven.  Is there any hope in sealing such a thing from the front, and if so what type of product would be worth a shot?

The soils are clay in the area.
[image]

Comment: Is the outside above or below ground?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is leaking I would guess it is below grade, lucky it is only a couple of feet. First I would dig out the area at the crack now the tough part , clean the wall at the crack (a pressure washer is handy in this case). I would fill the crack with hydraulic cement and let it cure then coat the area with a water proof coating last refill the hole.